# Как запросом получить даты наиболее близкие к текущей дате?

Tags: sql, oracle

Есть таблица, в которой один из столбцов это даты продаж разных товаров.

Как можно выбрать даты, которые наиболее близки к текущей дате?

Answer (score 2):

На таких  данных:

```
        ID SOLD
---------- -------------------
         1 2021-06-01 02:24:00
         2 2021-06-02 04:48:00
         3 2021-06-03 07:12:00
         4 2021-06-12 09:36:00
         5 2021-06-12 12:00:00
         6 2021-06-27 16:48:00
```

Ожидаю получить две записи от 2021-06-12, они наиболее близки к текущей дате 2021-06-27.

Так получаюю их:

```
select * 
from sales
where trunc(sold) = (
    select max (trunc (sold))
    from sales 
    where sold < trunc (sysdate)
    );

        ID SOLD              
---------- -------------------
         4 2021-06-12 12:00:00
         5 2021-06-12 09:36:00
```